# Vue.js Vuex Firebase - Cannot get user from store

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuex

In my router, I have a beforeEach guard to check for protected pages..
When I display the store state,  I can see that there is a user ( bind to Firebase)  but I cannot get it , even display it ...

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log('ROUTER from: ', from, ' to: ', to, '  next: ', next)
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    console.log('protected page')
    console.log('store state: ', store.state)
    console.log('store state user: ', store.state.user)
    if (!store.state.user || !store.state.user.emailVerified || store.state.user.isAnonymous) {
      // console.log('ROUTER auth user: ', store.state.user)
      next({
        path: '/signin'
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    // console.log('ROUTER no auth: ', to)
    next()
  }
})
```

console.log output from Chrome dev tools

[image: console.log]

Comment: Do you use vuex modules?

Comment: Does `console.log('store state user: ', store.state.user)` print anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the User is Auth, you can use the method `onAuthStateChanged()` of firebase auth in you `main.js` if you are using vue-cli. See the example:

in you `main.js` after firebase inicialization

```
// Initialize Firebase
    let config = {
       apiKey: "you_app_generated_key",
       authDomain: "youapp-randomkey.firebaseapp.com",
       databaseURL: "https://youapp-randomkey.firebaseio.com",
       projectId: "youapp-randomkey",
       storageBucket: "gs://youapp-randomkey.appspot.com/",
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    //If the event onAuthStateChanged() is emited
    //You can can verify if the user is auth or not.
    //If he isn't you can set null for the user.

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

        if (user) {

            this.$store.dispatch('setUser', user) //set the User

        } else {

            this.$store.dispatch('setUser', null) //set null because he is notauth
        }

    })


    }
})
```

Now in any part of you project you can verify if there's a User or not in you state.

If there's a User, To display it, it depends of what user prop you need to display.

When need to display or get user: name, email and photo. I do:

```
let user = state.user
let user_id: user.uid
let user_name: user.displayName,
let user_photo: user.photoURL
```

.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: thanks for feedback ... I dit it first, but later on I moved it  as an action ( bindAuth() and  excited when my App component is created ... 
however your comment put me on tracks ... I checked again my main.js and discover this previous code ... still there  so duplicated 
 I should have erased  so your answer is right and it help me ... I vote for it